# using `sass` to `@import` or `@use` css file in a classname with `cra 4`

Tags: css, sass, styles, node-sass

I am using `sass: 1.4.x` and with create-react-app 4..

all i am doing it import a css file in a custom class and my file is not getting imported..

```
.umaiShopDashBoardParent {
  @import '~react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
}
```

as attached in the screenshot i am getting `'unknown property name'`...

[image: unknown property name]

However if i am using `node-sass@latest` and using the above class it worked fine..

is there something new in dart-sass that i am missing.. as i am not able to load this file unless i move it outside of the classname `.umaiShopDashBoardParent` and put in root

Moreover, i try to use `@use` to use a css file

i get the following error:

```sh
resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/styles/main.scss)
SassError: Cant find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use '~react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles/vendor/_all.scss 1:1  @import
  src/styles/main.scss 2:11        root stylesheet
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import css/scss file into a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307455/import-css-scss-file-into-a-class)

Comment: doing as above gives error:
```
 (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/styles/main.scss)
SassError: This function isn't allowed in plain CSS.
    ╷
152 │   color: darken(#cacccd,10%);
    │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules/react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css 152:10  @import
```

Comment: however, when i swtich to `node-sass` it works.. not sure why `sass`  is not picking it :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494045/blueprintjs-sasserror-path-fill-5c7080-isnt-a-valid-css-value

--->   this might be a similar question.. however i want to use sass and not node-sass

Answer (score -1):

The issue was in react-dates css file `react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css`...

It is not compatible with `sass` , there a issue i created for it here:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/2152

Moreover, a/c to the link below the issue is fixed but not yet deployed to release at the time of writing this answer..

For more details check this link:
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/2081